# Use different ID for show route in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

Show route works with /example/{id}. So when I create a product with an id = 1 , `show/1` will show me that product.

However, I want to make a unique key for id, so only people with the url can view it. Unique id = 21J2@29SAHAS198S so product 1 will show with `/show/21J2@29SAHAS198S.`

I have tried to make a parameter in migrations 'key' which is `$random = str_random(40);` I then set $key to primary id in the table model. This still doesnt work

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your products table create a filed `code` something like this and define it as unique and at time of product creation insert random string in it and then specify this filed in your `Product` model as the route key like this.

Product Model

```
class Product extends Model {

  public function getRouteKeyName()
  {
    return 'code';
   }
}
```

Now define in your route `show/{product}`;

```
Route::get('show/{product}', 'ProductController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductController extends Controller {

  public function show(Request $request, App\Product $product){

     dd($product)
  }
}
```

For details check **Implicit Binding** in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Thanks, for some reason its not working. is it possible to start a chat ?

Comment: ah my mistake should be `Route::get('show/{product}', 'ProductController@show');` updated my answer

Comment: maybe im using the wrong create controller. Maybe i should have explained more. User creates a product. say they click on a computer category button, then it asks to add product information. One product per category. So when i got to product create the product/1 also corresponds to the category(computer) so the two are linked

Comment: here 1 is product id or category id ? i think it  doesn't have to be problem. did you try my answer ?

Comment: How do I change so it displays code as the id ? right now the href is product/{{$product->id}} which just shows old code. I need it to show the new code

Comment: add `product/{{$product->code}}` in your href, be sure you must have `code` filed in your table

Comment: it worked but i have one more question can i ask in chat?

Comment: sure what is that ? you can start chat and if it work then you can upvote too for future user

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 encode to encode the ID parameter when you create URL for example 
**example/{base64_encoded_id}**.

And when you use that ID parameter in your code then just use base64 decode function to get original ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression Constraints like below:

`Route::get('example/{id}', function ($id) {
    //..
})->where('id', '/[a-z0-9A-Z@]*/');`

For detail information regarding Laravel Route with regular expression follow below link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

if you want set string $key to Primary Keys, you must set

```
public $incrementing = false
protected $keyType = 'string'
```

in your Product Model

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#Primary-Keys